# Need help with making commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I’m trying to make a commutative diagram. The below image is output of following latex programming which is obviously not something I want. Can someone please fix it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\[ \begin{tikzcd}
\operatorname{Id'}(V)\times \operatorname{Id'}(B) \arrow{r} \arrow[swap]{d}{\theta \times id} & Id'( V \otimes^{\text {tmin}} B) \arrow[swap]{d}{\theta} \\%
\operatorname{Id'}(A(V)) \times \operatorname{Id'}(B) \arrow{r}{\Phi} & \operatorname{Id'}(A(V)\otimes^{\text {min}} B)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oam` package sets `\mathsurround=1pt`, which breaks `tikz-cd`.

It's possible to fix this by using proper Ti*k*Z/PGF methods. This won't interfere with the value of `\mathsurround` outside diagrams.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,latexsym,amssymb} % these packages are required
%\usepackage{theorem}                % please use one of this two options for theorems
\usepackage{amsthm}                % please use one of this two options for theorems
\usepackage{mathrsfs,upref}         % not so essential, but part of journal style
\usepackage{mathptmx}               % Journal is printed with poscript fonts:

\usepackage{oam}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  zerosurround/.code={\mathsurround=0pt},   % define a suitable key
  every diagram/.append style=zerosurround, % add it to every diagram
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  \operatorname{Id}'(V)\times \operatorname{Id'}(B)
    \arrow[r]
    \arrow[d,swap,"\theta \times id"]
  &
  \operatorname{Id}'(V \otimes^{\mathrm{tmin}} B)
    \arrow[d,swap,"\theta"]
  \\
  \operatorname{Id}'(A(V)) \times \operatorname{Id'}(B)
    \arrow[r,"\Phi"]
  &
  \operatorname{Id}'(A(V)\otimes^{\mathrm{min}} B)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note the “modern” syntax for arrows that's much more flexible than the “legacy” one. Also, `\operatorname{Id'}` should better be `\operatorname{Id}'` and `\text` should be `\mathrm`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{tikzcd}
\operatorname{Id'}(V)\times \operatorname{Id'}(B) 
  \arrow{r} \arrow[swap]{d}{\theta \times id} & 
    Id'( V \otimes^{\text {tmin}} B) \arrow[swap]{d}{\theta} \\%
\operatorname{Id'}(A(V)) \times \operatorname{Id'}(B)
   \arrow{r}{\Phi} & 
   \operatorname{Id'}(A(V)\otimes^{\text {min}} B)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried by copying yours still the arrows are not coming at right place, I don’t understand why is this happening

Comment: First try deleting the auxiliary files. Maybe you are using a custom installation...MiKTeX basic?

Comment: Well, I’m doing it on overleaf website. Even with your coding I got the exact same output given in question

Comment: Do you get any errors? Any warnings? Look at the .log file produced by the compilation

Comment: Seems this is happening because of “oam” package but I have to use it as its format of journal. Anything can be done ?

Comment: I cannot figure out what the "oam" package is and where it can be downloaded. For sure it is not on CTAN

Comment: It's available here http://oam.ele-math.com/submission under the topic submission of papers.

Comment: You have to declare 
`\mathsurround=0pt 
\[ \begin{tikzcd}... 
\end{tikzcd} \] \mathsurround=1pt`

Comment: Thank you very much, Ivan!